# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException when AsyncTask with Parser is called More than once

Tags: android, parsing, android-asynctask, gson

I'm using AsyncTask to retrieve data from backend server and parsing it using gson parser. I'm getting com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException when I execute AsyncTask more than once

### This is my Parser with Async

```
public class ParseTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JsonObject> {

public JsonObject jsonObject;
String url;

@Override
protected JsonObject doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    url = arg0[0];
    try {
        URL uRL = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) uRL.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        jsonObject = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) connection.getContent())).getAsJsonObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JsonObject json) {
    super.onPostExecute(json);
}
```

}

---

This is my main activity

```
public class DrillOneFragment extends Activity {

private static String url = "abc";
private static final String TAG_YEAR = "year";
LayoutParams params;
View view;
private JsonObject result;
String q;
String[] qq = { "2013", "2014" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.a);
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_YEAR, qq[i]));
    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
    url += "?" + paramString;
    try {
        result = new ParseTask().execute(url).get();
        Log.e(qq[i], result.toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

}

---

This is my logcat

---

```
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735): 

com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 6 path $
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:65)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.example.tester.ParseTask.doInBackground(ParseTask.java:25)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.example.tester.ParseTask.doInBackground(ParseTask.java:1)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735): Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 6 path $
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1573)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.checkLenient(JsonReader.java:1423)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.doPeek(JsonReader.java:546)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.peek(JsonReader.java:429)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.google.gson.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:60)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    ... 8 more
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.example.tester.DrillOneFragment.onCreate(DrillOneFragment.java:41)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5050)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
08-19 17:14:51.937: W/System.err(14735):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

---

---

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can we see the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

you misused the call to AsyncTask class, you must instantiate the class and then define parameters, connect and finally get the JSON objects. Finally remember to use the motodo onPostExecute () as output. You may not

```
result = new ParseTask().execute(url).get();
```

you must do the following. This code works fine for me

```
private class GetArticulosParam extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    public GetArticulosParam() {
        contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Por Favor, Espere...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        // String
        // url1="http://pracsysonline.dyndns.org/ListaArticulos/consultaParam.php";
        String url1 = "http://"+direccion+"/ListaArticulos/consultaParam.php";
        String param = arg0[0];
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param", param));
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();
        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr =sh.makeServiceCall(url1,ServiceHandler.POST,params);
        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_DESC);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_CODE);

                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    Log.e("PRUEBA", img);
                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put(TAG_DESC, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_CODE, name);
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        miAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
        setListAdapter(miAdapter);
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

then the class ServiceHandler

```
public class ServiceHandler {

static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;

public ServiceHandler() {

}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method) {
    return this.makeServiceCall(url, method, null);
}

/*
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                UrlEncodedFormEntity encodedEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8");
                encodedEntity.setContentEncoding(HTTP.UTF_8);
                httpPost.setEntity(encodedEntity);
                //httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        //codigo pruebna
        response = new Scanner(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        /*httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        response = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity,"utf-8");*/

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

}

Comment: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: thanks for the answer. I had used the method provided by you earlier but later i found that this method is deprecated. So i used gson library instead.

Comment: what do you think is the error in the code provided by me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong AsyncTask working class to use as well, you must do the following

```
protected void onPostExecute(JsonObject json) {
super.onPostExecute(json);
result=json;
```

}

then you should work from onPostExecute to do what I should do, remember that being a secondary thread code block the main thread is still running so would generate NullPointer. You would be empty accessing objects.It is why we must work from onPostExecute